# ZeroMQ / ØMQ / 0MQ how to get started?

Tags: c#, .net, message, zeromq

I am trying to use ZeroMQ / ØMQ / 0MQ (which ever you prefer) on Windows using [C# Binding](http://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq). Is there any beginner materials out there? Do I need to register ZeroMQ DLL on Windows or something in order to run the C# Binding samples (local_lat / remote_lat)?

**Updated**:
After a few hours I've got zeromq / ruby working on Ubuntu 10.04. I've left a comment on [this blog post](http://willj.net/2010/08/01/basic-zero-mq-ruby-example/) indicating how to get zeromq / ruby installed on Ubuntu 10.04. **But I am still trying to figure out how to run a simple sample on Windows / C# .NET.**

> install rvm on ubuntu 10.04
>
> http://www.christopherirish.com/2010/08/25/how-to-install-rvm-on-ubuntu-10-04/
>
> install zeromq
>
> http://gist.github.com/574656
>
> if you get error after zeromq is installed, try this one to update the library
>
> http://www.apparatusproject.org/blog/tag/zeromq/

Comment: So no one has done this before?

Comment: Have a look on [github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4) and [github.com/metadings/zguide](https://github.com/metadings/zguide/tree/master/examples/C%23/)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just started to play with `0MQ` on my machine. <del>I uploaded the simple server/client with pre-compiled libraries (clrzmq and zmq-2.0.9 from github) to bitbucket</del>. I hope this helps you also to get started with `0MQ` on Windows.

EDIT: A lot has happend since this question and answer. Now it is [way easier to install and use ZeroMQ](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=zeromq).

Comment: What's the linker file for when I use Visual Studio to compile the project?

Comment: It seems this link has been removed. Is this true?

Answer (score 8):

A new version of the ZeroMQ CLR binding is available at [clrzmq2](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq2/)

The reason for the new binding is that it is not backwards compatible with the first, but it is more idiomatic C#, and it supports the full feature set of 2.0.9.

It is also cross platform and should run on both Windows and Linux, x86/-64.

A lot of the examples from the 0MQ guide are now ported to C#, should be up to chapter 3 within the next day or so.

If something isn't working raise an issue on github or contact the ZeroMQ dev mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Docker [check this out](https://github.com/brett--anderson/ZeroMQ-hello-world-docker-cpp). It will run the hello world C++ example from the zguide. The Docker containers take care of setting up and configuring the libraries needed by ZMQ and CMake and are completely portable.

I also created an example for C [here](https://github.com/brett--anderson/ZeroMQ-hello-world-docker)

Both of these use ZeroMQ version 4.2.1 and CMake 3.6, but I mention in the readme how to change these values. They will get you up and running and then you can dig into the Docker files to see what steps are required to get things running with Ubuntu 14.04.

Alternatively take a look at the repository and examine the `Dockerfile` and `CMakeLists.txt` files in either `zmq-hello-world-client-node` or `zmq-hello-world-server-node`. The Dockerfile lists the steps needed to setup the required libraries on Ubuntu 14.04, the CMakeLists.txt file finds the necessary includes and creates a make file that will link them in when you build the project